# AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'time'

Tags: python, time, attributeerror

I am currently getting this error in my code

> AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'time'

I have not seen an exact instance to mine I have seen some changes to dtype=object but I am unsure how to implement that and why I would need to. This is a pretty straight forward function.

```
import time

class lastCycle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lastTime = time.time()
        self.time = 0.0

    def timer(self, time):
        if (time.time() - self.lastTime) > self.time:
            self.lastTime = time.time()
            return True
        else:
            return False

statusUpdate = lastCycle().timer(1.0)
```

Comment: Your `time` argument is shadowing the `time` module. You don't even seem to be using the argument, just remove it

Comment: Check out if the below solution solves you query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
```

class lastCycle():
    def **init**(self):
        self.lastTime = time.time()
        self.time = 0.0

```
def timer(self, threshold):
    if (time.time() - self.lastTime) > threshold:
        self.lastTime = time.time()
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried changing the variable name before but what I missed was not using self.threshold. I guess I do not need to do this since it is being declared in this function.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use module name `time` as keyword here:

```
def timer(self, time):
    if (time.time() - self.lastTime) > self.time:
        self.lastTime = time.time()
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I guess this is the solution you are looking for:

```
def timer(self, timeVal):
    if (timeVal - self.lastTime) > self.time:
        self.lastTime = time.time()
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. But the time value was for the self.time not time.time() I see my error was using time as well as declaring self before it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using it, like that:
time = my_function() *

and in my_function(): ...code... time.time() ...code...

So, you need to change time *, and it done

Comment: This has already been mostly answered - how is your answer better than the other current ones? Does it have any different parts?